# App consumes an extreme amount of API calls in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am tired and sad and frustrated here, and feel like a total moron. I am very sorry if my post is too long and not very well put together, but im beggin anyone with some experience here to please give me some advice.

I am currently testing out a app I have created to let people add events, search for events, comment on and get notified about changes in events they have signed up for. I have used Azure Mobile Service for this, and it all seems to have worked well. This is mostly a learning app for me, since I am very much a noob.

Now we are nearing launch of the app, and I have started to look at the numbers in Azure. I am on the free version right now, where 16k api calls a day are free (will move to priced tier on launch) - but the numbers look completely off the hook here!

Every day 2-3 devices seem to run up 600-700 API calls. I do run the testing app hard, of course, but I guess some user might do that to.

So - 4% of the daily free calls are consumed by 3 devices. That means 33 users could fill the quota, and the first paid tier only gives room for 300 users.

Am I reading something wrong here? Is my app then not viable? I think it, even with my noobness, has a potentil to get a few thousand users. Does that mean Im gonna have to go to the top tier? Because I can not afford that.

Over to the stack part of the question:

I log the user in, I create the tables, and then when they hit search I do something like this:

```
                    eventenItemList = await eventenTable.Take (200).Where (item => item.Dateandtimeend >= DateAndTimeIn).
                    Where (item => item.Dateandtime <= DateAndTimeInEnd).
                    Where (item => item.Fylke == fylke).
                    Where (item => item.Pris <= MaksPris).ToListAsync ();
```

I would expect that to be a single API-call, but it seems to run up tens of calls - just there? How is that possible?

When the user is not in the app, I run a background service in Android that goes through a local db of events the user has created and then checks against the db for any changes to them. I do that like this:

```
        var table = db.Table<MyEvents> ();

                    foreach (var e in table) {
                        eventenItemList = await eventenTable.Where (item =>                item.Id == e.EventId).ToListAsync ();

                        if (eventenItemList.Count == 0) {

                        } else {
   //I here notify the user that something new is up - and what it is. Time changed, comments or whatever.
```

Im guessing this is stupid of me, since it probably makes one API call for each loop here? But in the numbers it just seems to do 2 calls - like I expect it to.

I am horribly lost here, people. I ran around a hundred random clicks around the app this evening - and racked up over 1500 api calls. I have been cold sweating since that. Any advice or info about how this api call-system works would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I recommend that you install Fiddler and see each call that is being made. You definitely will get one API call for each iteration of the loop in the last code listing.

Comment: Yes, I am a total moron. Thanks for the input! Working on changing it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have an easy answer for you, but don't panic!

1) Understand the API calls you're making. *Look at the requests you're making*. I believe everything is ultimately a call to a REST API, so you can reverse engineer your queries to your abstraction. This will be a critical step.

2) Understand your abstractions. Linq is a massive abstraction on top of all kinds of things. This provides great power, but also the danger of mentally oversimplifying the costs of what you're doing. What queries are you *actually making* to your backing store? Is it properly hitting high efficiency keys or are you paging through a table scan? (Assuming such a thing exists, I don't know). This loops back to #1.

3) Once you understand how your query is hammering the API calls, you'll have the data you need to begin fixing the problem.

The fact is you know you're using far more API calls than you anticipated. You know this. Now it's time to figure out how and what you can optimize about it. :)

Comment: You just gave me so much hope, Greg. Thank you so much. Will return when I know more. To the optimization!

Comment: Yes! You are such a hero, man. Thanks for the input. Accepting this as answer, and will update my question so others struggling can see some of the pitfalls.

Comment: Glad we could help. :)